# Местонахождение профиля Mozilla Firefox в Windows OS

Tags: windows, firefox

где профиль Mozilla? есть две папки. какая из них?

AppData\Roaming\Mozilla и AppData\Local\Mozilla

Comment: суд по тому, что имя каталога случайное, лучше искать по реально существующему файлу. Вот пример команды: **for /f %i in ('@dir /b/s %appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\prefs.js') do @echo %~dpi**

Answer (score 1):

Firefox сохраняет папку вашего профиля в этом месте на вашем компьютере, по умолчанию:
`C:\Users\<ваше имя пользователя для входа в Windows>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\`

[отсюда](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data)

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\

Win+R > "%appdata%/mozilla/firefox/profiles"